# Set Image as wallpaper using Intent

Tags: android, wallpaper

I am using the following code to set the wallpaper from an image in a drawable:

```
Intent setAsIntent = new Intent();
setAsIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
setAsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
setAsIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA");
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
        setAsIntent, "set as");
```

But when startActivity, it only shows a message:

> No apps can perform this action

Answer (score 2):

I did discover a workaround:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```

or try to use

```
WallpaperManager


wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();

mImageView.setImageURI(imagepath);
```

If you have image bitmap then use this

```
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(useThisBitmap);
```

In your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```